# Zabbix user-defined parameters

Tags: zabbix

I have the need of monitroing special serivce state via zabbix.
When i run on server

```
 supp@db3 ~ $ /etc/init.d/kannelgate zabbix
```

it prints a number in console  - 1 or 0 (service up/down)

What should I write in zabbix agent to get this output by agent and send it to zabbix server?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a user parameter like this by writing the following line into zabbix_agentd.conf:

```
UserParameter=kannelgate.state,/etc/init.d/kannelgate zabbix
```

Please see [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/userparameters) for more information on defining user parameters.

Comment: Yes, i already got it - by default zabbix agent reads stdout to send data, so no special data redirection required.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
UserParameter=kannelgate.state[*],/etc/init.d/kannelgate $1
```

So you can use one parameter for various services.

Two of your item keys can look like:

```
kannelgate.state["zabbix-agent"]
```

and

```
kannelgate.state["zabbix-server"]
```

Edit:
Thanks to Selivanov Pave, for mention the security issue. But have a look to the Zabbix docs:
[Zabbix Userparameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/userparameters)

Quote from this part:

> The following characters are not allowed:
>   \ ' " ` * ? [ ] { } ~ $ ! & ; ( ) < > | # @

You should really care about User Parameter if you enable "UnsafeUserParameter" on the Zabbix Agent side!

*In Zabbix 3.x docs the structure changed a bit, so you have to search in Zabbix Agent configuration.*

Comment: When using UserParameter with arguments, you should very carefully check given parameters in script. Otherwise compromising of monitoring server may lead to compromising of monitored hosts.